# Creating 2 different themes in less - Angular 5

Tags: angular, less

I am trying to figure out how to create different themes for my project. I already styled everything, and its quite big project, now I want to add a different theme.

Is there a way of creating 2 different less files that will somehow be included in style.less or whatever, and based on what I get from backend once a user logs in, choose which theme to display? Or any other way, I am looking for ideas.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Theming only certain components**

The `angular-material-theme` mixin will output styles for all components in the library. If you are only using a subset of the components (or if you want to change the theme for specific components), you can include `component-specific` theme mixins. You also will need to include the `mat-core-theme` mixin as well, which contains theme-specific styles for common behaviors (such as ripples).

[Read this article](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Comment: Why do you assume that this question is related to angular material?

Comment: He wants idea for his question . I think this article helping to his

Comment: Yeah I dont really want to use angular material, I was just wondering if there was some kind of "simple solution for this without using material